# How to remove virtualbox from brew when getting a "No such file or directory" error message

Tags: homebrew

Below is what I tried:

```
➜  ~ brew rm virtualbox
==> Uninstalling Cask virtualbox
Error: Failure while executing; `brew cask uninstall virtualbox-extension-pack` exited with 127. Here's the output:
No such file or directory - brew

➜  ~ brew cask rm virtualbox
==> Uninstalling Cask virtualbox
Error: Failure while executing; `brew cask uninstall virtualbox-extension-pack` exited with 127. Here's the output:
No such file or directory - brew
➜  ~
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally fixed it with:

```
brew cask install --force virtualbox virtualbox-extension-pack
brew cask rm virtualbox-extension-pack virtualbox
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have an error with brew.

```
Error: `brew cask` is no longer a `brew` command. Use `brew <command> --cask` instead.
```

You can try

```
brew install --cask --force virtualbox virtualbox-extension-pack
brew rm --cask virtualbox-extension-pack VirtualBox
```